# Any way to deal with cropping sprite images - Python/Pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite

I would like to use some images for my sprites in pygame, while i need many images for the animations they are all not cropped to the edges of the actual image. So either I need to crop every single image or I can use spritesheets. Is there any other way to do this fast?

Comment: For now i will be using different image sets that are cropped, but still any answers will help me and others for future programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently created a chess program in which I used a spritesheet including all chess pieces. First I imported the spritesheet and transformed it to the correct size I needed (SQW is the with of each square on the chess board). Then I cropped it in a nested for loop to obtain a list of piece images. I needed a nested for loop since the spritesheet contained 2 rows with 6 piece images, black and white pieces on each row. Code looks somthing like this:

```
SPRITE = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('imgs/pieces.png'), (int(SQW*6), int(SQW*2)))
PIECES = [None] * 12
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        PIECES[j + i*6] = pygame.Surface.subsurface(SPRITE, (j*SQW, i*SQW, SQW, SQW))
```